# Can I use Firebase for applications that has just database operations?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a budget management application, which needs to store users incomes and expenses then show back to user. I am using SQLite in my project which takes lots of code to save and retrieve data. I wonder whether I can use Firebase just to save and retrieve data. Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure you can! Just just use the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) service. Think of it like a JSON-ish storage in the cloud :-)

As a bonus, you can [enable offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) and query your data even offline:

> Firebase applications work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. In addition, Firebase provides tools for persisting data locally, managing presence, and handling latency.
>
> The Firebase Realtime Database stores data returned from a query for use when offline. For queries constructed while offline, the Firebase Realtime Database continues to work for previously loaded data. If the requested data hasn't loaded, the Firebase Realtime Database loads data from the local cache. When network connectivity is available again, the data loads and will reflect the query.

You can enable *disk persistence* with just one line of code:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Firebase database *writes*, while offline, would be added to a queue which would sync once network is back and online.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do I need to have internet connection everytime for the operations ?

Comment: @IsaArıkan I updated my answer with further details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paulo.